# How to use regular expression to retrieve data in python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string defined as,

```
content = "f(1, 4, 'red', '/color/down1.html');    
f(2, 5, 'green', '/color/colorpanel/down2.html');    
f(3, 6, 'blue', '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html');"
```

Here is the code I tried but it doesn't work:

```
results = re.findall(r"f(.*?)", content)
for each in results:
    print each
```

How to use regular expression to retrieve the links within the content? Thanks.

Comment: You should show us the code and regexes that you've tried already.

Comment: Here is the code I tried but it doesn't work. 
results = re.findall(r"f(.*?)", content)

  for each in results:
      print each

Comment: You probably want to use re.findall(re_pattern, content), where re_pattern is your regex.

Comment: That is exactly my question. What would be the correct pattern in order to retrieve the link.

Comment: What links are you referring to?, is it the last part as `down3.html` or the whole link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can learn the basic regexes on https://regex101.com/ and http://regexr.com/

```
In [4]: import re

In [5]: content = "f(1, 4, 'red', '/color/down1.html');    \
   ...: f(2, 5, 'green', '/color/colorpanel/down2.html');   \
   ...: f(3, 6, 'blue', '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html');"

In [6]: p = re.compile(r'(?=/).*?(?<=.html)')

In [7]: p.findall(content)
Out[7]: 
['/color/down1.html',
 '/color/colorpanel/down2.html',
 '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html']
```

**.*?** matches any character (except for line

***?** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)

You can also just get the last `/`

```
In [8]: p2 = re.compile(r'[^/]*.html')

In [9]: p2.findall(content)
Out[9]: ['down1.html', 'down2.html', 'down3.html']
```

**[^/]*** Match a single character not present in the list below

*** Quantifier** — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

**/** matches the character / literally (case sensitive)

**.** matches any character (except for line terminators)
html matches the characters html literally (case sensitive).

Or, you can extract all the data in `f()`

```
In [15]: p3 = re.compile(r"(?=f\().*?(?<=\);)")

In [16]: p3.findall(content)
Out[16]: 
["f(1, 4, 'red', '/color/down1.html');",
 "f(2, 5, 'green', '/color/colorpanel/down2.html');",
 "f(3, 6, 'blue', '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html');"]
```

Comment: Regarding   p = re.compile(r'(?=/).*?(?<=.html)'), why not simply  p = re.compile(r'(?=/).*(?<=.html)') ?What is the purpose to add? after *? Thanks.

Comment: @dullboy, I added explanation in the answer, if you think  my answer solved your problem, please consider accept my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
re.findall(r"f\(.*,.*,.*, '(.*)'", content)
```

Comment: That is really a smart one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like so:

```
import re

content = """f(1, 4, 'red', '/color/down1.html');    
    f(2, 5, 'green', '/color/colorpanel/down2.html');    
    f(3, 6, 'blue', '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html');"""

print re.findall(r"(\/[^']+?)'", content)
```

Output:

```
['/color/down1.html', '/color/colorpanel/down2.html', '/color/colorpanel/colorlibrary/down3.html']
```

Regex:

`(\/[^']+?)'` - match `/` followed by 1 or more non `'` characters till first occurence of `'` and capture in group1.