# How to extract href links between <h1></h1> in Python?

Tags: python

I am new with Python and I'm trying to learn web scraping.

I have the following code and would like to know how to get/print the href or the link:

<.h1><.a href="https://www.nytimes.com/tips"> Got a confidential news tip?

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42173719/how-to-use-regular-expression-to-retrieve-data-in-python/42173798#42173798

Comment: another one similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3075550/how-can-i-get-href-links-from-html-using-python

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to get this work done:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

response = urlopen("http://someurl.com")
page_source = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, 'html.parser')
x = soup.find_all('h1')
print (x)
```

then all you have to do is use the `re` module and extract data from the output.